# call ForeignKey and count it on django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to count that how many employees in every department and show it on django template.

here my `models.py`

```
class Company(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='Tidak ada deskripsi')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("system:company_list")

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, default=0, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='company')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("system:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

and here my `views.py`

```
class CompanyListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'companys'
    model = models.Company
```

and here my `company_list.html`

```
{% for company in companys %} 

<tr>
    <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ companys.employee.count }}</td>
    <td>{{ company.desc }}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Iam trying count the company with `{{ companys.count }}` and its work. and i think it will gonna be `{{ companys.employee.count }}` for counting the employee. but its dint work.

did i miss something?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `{{ company.company.count }}` to have it work, because of your `related_name` : *company = models.ForeignKey(Company, default=0, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, **related_name='company'**)*

[More info can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

It's suggested, but not required, that the name of a `related_name` be a plural of the current model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, default=0, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, related_name='employees')
```

So it that case, you would have in template

```
{{ company.employees.count }} # count
{{ company.employees.all }} # All employees
```

Comment: still not working with `{{ companys.company.count }}`. also better use plural for every `related_name` ?...

Comment: you need to change the related_name in your model, if you want to use it like `company.employees.all`

Comment: `company` not `companys`.

Comment: ah working now, will accept soon. one more question `.all` need plural `related_name` ?...

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. *It's suggested that the name be a plural of the current model...*

Comment: I just updated my answer, I added a reference to Django Documentation